# Algorithm to find transform random pairs into polar coordinates

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have some pairs of real numbers $(\rho_1,\alpha_1),\dots (\rho_n, \alpha_n)$. I know that all my $\rho$'s are positive, but there is no constraints on my $\alpha$'s. I want to find a function $\phi$ such as $((\rho_1,\theta_1),\dots,(\rho_n,\theta_n)$ are *some* cartesian products, with $\theta_i = \phi(\rho_i,\alpha_i)$.

Is there a way to find such a $\phi$?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the relation between $\alpha_i$ and $\theta_i$ to be?

Comment: If whenever $(\rho_i,\alpha_i)=(\rho_j,\alpha_j)$, $\theta_i=\theta_j$, then yes, of course. But I don't think that's what you meant to ask. Could you explain more clearly what you want?

Comment: @ZhenLin there is no relation between $\alpha_i$ and $\rho_i$, they are just given.

Comment: @tomasz Basically I want a bijective transformations that will make my pairs polar coordinates.

Comment: @S4M: You haven't explained what your inputs are!

Comment: @ZhenLin they are just some inputs. actually the $\alpha$'s are positive. I don't know what it changes to the problem, as I am hoping to find some kind of generic solution.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Yes, that will do the trick I suppose! I can't believe I didn't think of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood this correctly, you want a bijection from $\mathbb{R^+}\times\mathbb{R^+}$ to $\mathbb{R^+}\times[0,2\pi)$. How about:

$$
\phi(\rho_i, \alpha_i) = \left(\rho_i, 2\pi\tanh(\alpha_i)\right)
$$

Here is a plot of $2\pi\tanh(x)$ on $[0,3]$:

[image: tanh]

Comment: Yes, this one will do the trick. And I can always tweak a bit the $tanh^{-1}$ function if I am not happy with it... Thanks!

Comment: @S4M - Happy to help! Please note that it's $\tanh$ (without $^{-1}$). I made a mistake in a previous comment.